# my D7 batch is running with every request to anywhere on my site

Tags: routes, batch-operations

I'm writing a batch module and for some reason every time I load any page on my site, the batch is running.  The other weird thing that may be related is that the $context['sandbox'] is not being preserved between iterations, so every time around it resets the progress count and starts over. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  This is a batch module that worked fine under D6, I made some changes based on what I thought was different in D7, but apparently i've really broken something.

here's my code for the entire module:

```
function batch_add_freetags_perm() {
  return array('batch: add editorial free tags to nodes');
}

function batch_add_freetags_menu() {
  $items['admin/content/batch_add_freetags'] = array(     
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('batch_add_freetags_form'),
);
return $items;
}

function batch_add_freetags_form() {
      $form = array();
      $form['import'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Import Free Tags'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      );

      $form['import']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Import'),
      );
      return $form;
}

function batch_add_freetags_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      batch_add_freetags_start();
}

function batch_add_freetags_start() {
  $batch = array(
    'title' => t('Tagging all Nodes'),
    'operations' => array(
        array('batch_add_freetags_process', array())
    ),
    'finished' => 'batch_add_freetags_finished',
    'init_message' => t('tag processing has started.'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total nodes.'),
    'error_message' => t('Batch has encountered an error.'),
  );
  batch_set($batch);
}
```

This is what seems to run every time (I only want it to run when a certain form is submitted, of course.) :

```
function batch_add_freetags_process( &$context) {
  if (empty($context['sandbox'])) {
    $context['sandbox'] = array();
    $context['results'] = array();
    $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = 0;

    // get data from the old d6 database
    $query = Database::getConnection(SOURCE_DB_KEY, SOURCE_DB_KEY)
      ->select('term_node', 'tn');
    $query->fields('tn', array('nid', 'tid'));
    $query->join('term_data', 'td', 'td.tid = tn.tid');
    $query->fields('td', array('vid'));
    $query->condition('td.vid', 15);
    $result = $query->execute();

    // set the maximum number of items from the results of the db call.
    $context['sandbox']['max'] = count($result->fetchAllAssoc('nid'));

    $context['results']['updated'] = 0;
    $context['results']['failures'] = 0;
    $context['results']['processed'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['max'] = 20;   // this is just for testing

  }

  // For this case, we decide that we can safely process
  // N nodes at a time without a timeout.
  $limit = 5;

  // bunch of actual operations commented out just to make sure this for loop is just a test while i'm figuring this out...

  for($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {
    // Update our progress information.
    $context['sandbox']['progress']++;
    $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = $i;
    $context['results']['processed']++;
    $context['message'] = t('Now processing tag "%name" for nid: %nid, <br/> completed tags for %current out of %max nodes', array('%name' => $term, '%nid' => $context['sandbox']['current_node'], '%current' => $context['sandbox']['progress'], '%max' => $context['sandbox']['max']));
  }  

  // Inform the batch engine that we are not finished,
  // and provide an estimation of the completion level we reached.
  if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
    $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
    // $context['finished'] = 1;   // make it stop!
  }
}

/**
 * Batch 'finished' callback
 */
function batch_add_freetags_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    // Here we do something meaningful with the results.
    $message = count($results) .' processed.';
    $message .= theme('item_list', $results);
  }
  else {
    // An error occurred.
    // $operations contains the operations that remained unprocessed.
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    $message = t('An error occurred while processing %error_operation with arguments: @arguments', array('%error_operation' => $error_operation[0], '@arguments' => print_r($error_operation[1], TRUE)));
  }
  drupal_set_message($message);
}
```

thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  There's a new D7 hook, hook_process(). So since my batch function was called "batch_add_freetags_process", it was getting called with every page load. I changed the name of the function and now things work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this function name `batch_add_freetags_process` to something else like `batch_add_freetags_batch` because hook_process() is utilized by Drupal and used to process theme variables for theme templates [hook_process](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_process/7)

Your code should look like the following:

```
function batch_add_freetags_start() {
  $batch = array(
    'title' => t('Tagging all Nodes'),
    'operations' => array(
        array('batch_add_freetags_batch', array())
    ),
    'finished' => 'batch_add_freetags_finished',
    'init_message' => t('tag processing has started.'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total nodes.'),
    'error_message' => t('Batch has encountered an error.'),
  );
  batch_set($batch);  
}

function batch_add_freetags_batch( &$context) {
  // body
}
```